# itextsharp 5 - pdf: Set chunk width

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to add a line of text in the pdf with a background which has width 100% of page's width. This is the `chunk`:

```
Chunk subjProp = new Chunk("SUBJECT PROPERTY");
subjProp.SetBackground(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
doc.Add(subjProp);
```

How I can set the background width to 100% of page width? Is it possible to set `margins` also?

Comment: The `Chunk` class doesn't exist anymore in the most recent versions of iText, so I assume that you are using an old version. Could you tell us which version you are using, and why you aren't using the latest version? If you are new at iText, it may save you time to start with iText 7 instead of with a version that is no longer supported. (And it may also save the time of the people wha want to answer.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am using iTextSharp 5

Comment: @BrunoLowagie tried to update to iTextSharp 7 but I get this error : 'Portable.BouncyCastle' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library